# Export Audacity tracklist with timestamps

Tags: audacity

I have a simple Audacity podcast project with several mp3 files in different tracks. Is it possible to export this list with the timestamps for each song?

I've added some fade effects to it, so the tracks start sooner than in the original playlist length.

Answer (score -1):

[Courtesy of Audacity QA](http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=86712)-

You can create [labels](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/label_tracks.html) for each song and can type in the time in hh:mm:ss and "Artist - Song" as the text for each label.

Then you can File > [Export Labels.](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/file_menu.html#Export_Labels...)... The start and end position of each label will be saved in the text file as a time in seconds.

You can convert a labels text file to a [Cue sheet](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Cue_sheets) using external tools.

If you File > [Export Multiple](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/export_multiple.html)... each exported audio file will take its name from the name you typed in the label. The Artist Name and Track Title can also be saved as metadata when you export as an audio file.

Edit: Ironically, I didn't realize that is literally your question over there at AudacityTeam's forums. Sorry it doesn't quite fit what you were hoping - [would this be of any interest?](https://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Importing_Timestamp_Information)

Comment: That script *imports* timestamps. I want to *export* my project timestamps as a text file to publish along with my podcast.